# Deploying a node application with HTTPS enabled to AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate, port

I want to deploy my app, which was developed locally with HTTPS enabled to AWS EC2. I am not sure if the only thing I need to do is to get a certificate from a free Certificate Authority (CA) like Let's Encrypt and upload that to EC2 to a directory called e.g SSL and reference that in my code, just like how I did it locally. And then at security groups - edit inbound rules - add rule - create an HTTPS port 443 - redirect to 3443 because my `app.js` file listens on that. Or is there something else involved I do not know about?

I would really appreciate if you could tell me if this is the right path?

```
const httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/server.crt')
};
const https = require('https').Server(httpsOptions, app);

const port = 3443;

https.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('listening on: *' + port);
});
```

Comment: Are you using ALB or ELB?

Comment: how can I determine that, sorry but I haven't encountered this terms?

Comment: If you're not using AWS application load balancer or elastic load balancer, then no problem.

Comment: no I am only using EC2.

Comment: Do you have any problem? Because it should work then

Comment: I haven't tried yet, I just wanted ask if it this the right approach before I get started.

Comment: Well that's a perfectly valid approach. I prefer using ALB, but it comes with an extra cost.

Comment: If you own the domain, I suggest you create the SSL/TLS cert from AWS Certificate Manager. Once the cert is provisioned, you could use it in you ELB. Then, you could have a setup like this: Route53 -> ELB(SSL) -> EC2(nodejs without SSL).